# Scraping test with beautifulsoup on flipkart with error

Tags: beautifulsoup

I have trying to write a script to **scrape** data on [flipkart](https://www.flipkart.com/search?q=iphone&sort=recency_desc). Bellow the code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = 'https://www.flipkart.com/search?q=iphone&sort=recency_desc'
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

containers = page_soup.findAll("div", {"class": "_3liAhj"})

container = containers[0]

for container in containers:
    title_container = container.findAll("a", {"class": "_2cLu-l"})
    title = title_container[0].text

     price_container = container.findAll("div", {"class": "_1vC4OE"})
     price = price_container[0].text

     rating_container = container.findAll("span", {"class": "_2_KrJI"})
     rating = rating_container[0].text

     print("title : " + title)
     print("price : " + price)
     print("rating : " + rating)
```

The results are like this:

```
title : Apple iPhone SE (White, 128 GB)
price : ₹47,800
rating : 4.6
```

And I have this error at the end of the result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 22, in <module>
    rating = rating_container[0].text
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I think because  some products has no rating. What is the mistake and how can I avoid this error?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some items don't have rating, so you need take care of it.

For example (no rating is substituted with `-`):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.flipkart.com/search?q=iphone&sort=recency_desc'

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

for product in soup.select('[data-id]'):
    title = product.select_one('a + a')['title']
    product_rating = product.select_one('span[id^="productRating_"]')
    product_rating = product_rating.get_text(strip=True) if product_rating else '-'
    price = product.find(lambda t: t.name=='div' and t.text.startswith('₹')).div.get_text(strip=True)
    print('{:<10} {:<5} {}'.format(price, product_rating, title))
```

Prints:

```
₹47,800    4.6   Apple iPhone SE (White, 128 GB)
₹47,800    4.6   Apple iPhone SE (Red, 128 GB)
₹47,800    4.6   Apple iPhone SE (Black, 128 GB)
₹42,500    4.6   Apple iPhone SE (White, 64 GB)
₹58,300    4.6   Apple iPhone SE (Black, 256 GB)
₹42,500    4.6   Apple iPhone SE (Red, 64 GB)
₹58,300    4.6   Apple iPhone SE (Red, 256 GB)
₹42,500    4.6   Apple iPhone SE (Black, 64 GB)
₹58,300    4.6   Apple iPhone SE (White, 256 GB)
₹1,21,300  4.7   Apple iPhone 11 Pro (Space Grey, 256 GB)
₹1,17,100  4.7   Apple iPhone 11 Pro Max (Silver, 64 GB)
₹73,600    4.7   Apple iPhone 11 (Black, 128 GB)
₹999       -     CallSmith Screen Guard & Protector Applicator Accessory Combo for iPhone XR/ 11
₹73,600    4.7   Apple iPhone 11 (Yellow, 128 GB)
₹68,300    4.7   Apple iPhone 11 (Yellow, 64 GB)
₹1,17,100  4.7   Apple iPhone 11 Pro Max (Gold, 64 GB)
₹73,600    4.7   Apple iPhone 11 (Green, 128 GB)
₹73,600    4.7   Apple iPhone 11 (Purple, 128 GB)
₹68,300    4.7   Apple iPhone 11 (Green, 64 GB)
₹1,17,100  4.7   Apple iPhone 11 Pro Max (Midnight Green, 64 GB)
₹73,600    4.7   Apple iPhone 11 (Red, 128 GB)
₹73,600    4.7   Apple iPhone 11 (White, 128 GB)
₹68,300    4.7   Apple iPhone 11 (White, 64 GB)
₹68,300    4.7   Apple iPhone 11 (Black, 64 GB)
₹68,300    4.7   Apple iPhone 11 (Red, 64 GB)
₹158       -     HOBBYTRONICS Tempered Glass Guard for Apple iPhone 11, Apple iPhone XR
₹1,06,600  4.7   Apple iPhone 11 Pro (Silver, 64 GB)
₹1,06,600  4.7   Apple iPhone 11 Pro (Midnight Green, 64 GB)
₹68,300    4.7   Apple iPhone 11 (Purple, 64 GB)
₹1,06,600  4.7   Apple iPhone 11 Pro (Gold, 64 GB)
₹52,500    4.6   Apple iPhone XR (Blue, 64 GB)
₹52,500    4.6   Apple iPhone XR (White, 64 GB)
₹52,500    4.6   Apple iPhone XR (Yellow, 64 GB)
₹52,500    4.6   Apple iPhone XR ((PRODUCT)RED, 64 GB)
₹57,800    4.6   Apple iPhone XR (Coral, 128 GB)
₹57,800    4.6   Apple iPhone XR (White, 128 GB)
₹52,500    4.6   Apple iPhone XR (Coral, 64 GB)
₹52,500    4.6   Apple iPhone XR (Black, 64 GB)
₹135       -     HOBBYTRONICS Tempered Glass Guard for Apple iPhone 11, Apple iPhone XR
₹62,999    4.7   Apple iPhone XS (Gold, 64 GB)
```